# How to retrieve the preference from ListPreference?

Tags: android, listpreference

I have ListPreference that has 4 choices/options, I want to check for the selected option and make some code(if 1 is selected I do that, if 2 is selected I do other thing ...).
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="kernel">
 <item>TalonDev</item>
 <item>Semaphore</item>
 <item>SpeedMod</item>
 <item>Galaxian</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="kernel_return">
 <item>0</item>
 <item>1</item>
 <item>2</item>
 <item>3</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Is that true :

```
choice = prefs.getString("listPref_kernel", "0");
        if (choice == "0") {
        try {
             ...................
```

Comment: Is what true? You are using numeric digits in the XML (1/2/3/4) and "One" in the code - that can't work.

Comment: @sstn: i know, didn't see it, i made some other codes that's why i.... anyway, i edited the post, is that correct ?? thanks

Comment: It depends on how you use your arrays. You are free to try it...

Comment: @sstn: i think that it's not working because i coded a menu button that when i tap on it a file is created on the sdcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a PreferenceActivity:

Retrieve your shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
```

and retrieve the value:

```
String value = sp.getString(key, "default");
```

Optionally, you can set a SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener via

```
sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(...)
```

to be notified on any change.